# Passing DataSource clone to Subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to pass the datasource from main report to a subreport.

So I simply change **Connection Type** in *iReport* to **Use a datasource expression** and pass the **REPORT_DATA_SOURCE** parameter.

The report should generate a few hundred sites. And it computes 1 subreport per page.

The subreport only needs some lines of the datasource, so it uses his own WHERE in the query.

The problem is:

after changing the **Connection Type** from **Connection to Data Source**, the Report only displays the first site. It seems as if the subreport changes the dataset of the mainreport with its *WHERE* statement to only one line.

I have seen solutions for that
http://www.billmann.de/2011/12/01/jasperreports-subreport-datasource/
but when I try this, I get an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource

Are there other possibilities to clone a datasource? Or can I set something in Subreport, so that the datasource is not changed?

If I use *Connection* instead of *DataSource*, the Report works, but it renders 5 minutes and more, because every Subreport call generates its own Dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the above blog entry and the type cast to JRBeanCollectionDataSource is necessary as the datasource we use is a JRBeanCollectionDataSource and this JRDatasSurce supports the cloneDataSource() method.

Not all JRDataSources support such a method. If you have the chance to read in the database programmatically and fill the data in another JRDataSource like JRMapArrayDataSource you can use the cloneDataSource() method.

I am not sure if this solution works with the additional where clause.

Comment: The following error message 
occurs when I try to compile JRXML from iReport 3.0.0: 'The method cloneDataSource() is undefined for the type JRBeanCollectionDataSource'